# browser shows wrong DST when setting date

Tags: browser, timezone, dst

I need the browser to display a time (in milliseconds) sent from the server, in the user's local timezone & dst.

I noticed that when I ask the browser to show the current time (now) then the Timezone and DST are right.  However, when I set a date and ask the browser to show the set time then the Timezone is right but the DST is wrong.

Here is actual code:

```
x = new Date(1357012800*1000);
console.log("Javascript mydate:"+x);
now = new Date();
console.log("Javsscript now:"+now);
```

And the output from Chrome:

```
Javascript mydate:Mon Dec 31 2012 23:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) 
Javsscript now:Fri Apr 05 2013 11:04:41 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Can someone tell me how to make the browser display the date respecting the user's DST?  Why is it printing mydate in EST yet it's now time in EDT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date you provided, Dec 31 2012, Eastern Time was not in daylight savings.

Comment: Took me a while to figure that one out!